# Sound Not Found in c# Programming

Tags: wpf

This is my code:

```
   SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("sound/music.wav");
   player.Load();
   player.Play();
```

The sound exists in directory, but when I build it, the program throws `FileNotFoundException`.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Does it work if you provide full path of the sound file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a habit to always use `System.IO.File.Exists()` before actually asking .NET to use a file. This can save you from some run-time exceptions.

This is almost certainly because the relative path you have provided does not map to the current directory. I'm not even sure if that kind of forward-slash addresses is supported by `SoundPlayer`'s constructor or by .NET in general. Anyway, you should always use `System.IO.Directory` functions to construct your full path and pass that to `SoundPlayer`.